# How to use unicode characters in Eclipse File Search?

Tags: eclipse

We have some XML file that contains some invalid character, and the program says neither which file it is, nor which line number or character offset. It would be a few seconds work to fix the problem if I could just search for exactly that character, but I cannot find how to express a Unicode character in the file search (or at least I assume so, since the search returns nothing).

Neither 0x1e nor \u001e seem to match anything.

[EDIT] I mean, I can still change the code, and eventually find which file it is by catching the Exception, and using some kind of script/tool to find where exactly the character is, but I do believe it should be possible to search with Unicode in Eclipse, and that is what I am asking in this question.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a problem with the character encoding.

As you're going to need to perform a global / site-wide search to find the , you'll probably need to set the global text file encoding:

Preferences -> Workspace -> Text file encoding

This option may be under the 'General' section in Eclipse, depending on your setup and installed plugins etc.

Ensure that the encoding is set to UTF-8.

You will also need to escape the unicode character sequences, like so:

```
\u2665
```

(which I see you have tried)